# What is the opposite of "abstain"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

We were thinking originally in terms of voting, but of course "abstain" has a more general meaning, of which the antonym is probably "indulge".

But is there an opposite that would be more appropriate when the usage of abstain is related to abstaining from voting in an election?

Comment: Two things come to mind, and they're both quite different. One is describing a single act of voting: "cast their vote," etc., and the other is adjectives for someone who is a chronic voter: "vocal about their opinion," "never one to hold their tongue," "assertive," "partisan," "opinionated," "obstinate," "dogmatic," etc.

Comment: How come you can "abstain" but you cannot "stain" or "tain" at least in the meaning of "not refrain". I would be gruntled if someone could explain.

Comment: I was going to provide the answer "Do" but that doesn't seem to really meet the context in regards to voting, just general abstain.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In an election, the opposite of abstaining is **voting**, because ["abstaining"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abstain) in that context means "to refrain from casting one's vote".  The opposite of "not voting" is "voting".

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see how OP could have expected any other antonym, after explicitly specifying that he was only interested in the sense of *abstaining from voting*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the idea of casting a ballot that indicates an abstention (e.g. voting "present" in the US Congress) may muddy the waters a bit.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: We've always had that in the UK. It's called "spoilt ballot papers", and the number of such is normally reported if it's enough to be significant.

Answer (score 39):

I would say the opposite is *partake*.

> We all partook in the voting.

Comment: That gives me the impression it was a voluntary action - *which might well have been the case* -- but in Australia voting is compulsory and never voluntary. Hmmm, that probably says more about me than I'd like.

Comment: @pavium: So I guess your antonym would have to be *comply*?

Comment: No, I'll have to go with 'voting'. At every election, some wit reminds us to "vote early, and vote often"

Answer (score 28):

How about "participate"? Or perhaps "turned out" (to vote). Depends on the sentence, really.

Answer (score 13):

I voted up drm65's answer of contextual solution, to simply say **vote**.

However if you are looking for a term you might consider

- *participate* in voting | *abstain* from voting
- *vote* | *abstain* from voting
- *exercise* (or *consume*) your voting rights | *abstain* from voting
- *cast* a vote | *abstain* from voting

Comment: Good examples :)

Answer (score 7):

The opposite of ***abstain/refrain*** is to ***partake/participate/have***

Answer (score 5):

Maybe to "**assert** your vote" is what you're looking for?

Comment: Though this isn't a technical term.

Comment: does it need to be? The justification for my answer is that "abstain" carries the impression that you considered the candidates and, based on your judgment, decided to not vote. "Assert" similarly implies that you have considered the candidates and decidedly selected one to vote for.

Answer (score 4):

For pleasures, "partake."

For voting "participate."

Answer (score 0):

In terms of voting? There are several:

> balloting,
>   choosing,
>   deciding,
>   polling,
>   voting

Answer (score 0):

*Indulge* is the opposite of *abstain*.

You are not using *abstain* in the best context by applying it to voting.  *Abstain* and *indulge* have certain moral connotations.  Thus, a better bet would have been to use *refrain* and *partake*.

Comment: -1: The OP said that he already considered the general meaning of "abstain"; his entire question centers around its particular meaning in the context of voting.  By saying "You are not using abstain in the best context by applying it to voting", you are ignoring what the OP asked.

Answer (score -2):

Simple: Sustain.  (if you want to stick with the same suffix)

> –verb (used with object)
>   1. to support, hold, or bear up from below; bear the weight of, as a structure.
>   2. to bear (a burden, charge, etc.).
>   3. to undergo, experience, or suffer (injury, loss, etc.); endure without giving way or yielding.

(shamelessly stolen from http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sustain)

Both words come from the same root... meaning "to hold"... implying to support a vote (either for or against) or in the opposite... like abstain meaning to withhold support of a vote.