# Word for "a sudden death" 

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

A neighbour of mine died last week a moment after reaching his climax during the sexual intercourse with his young partner. He was 79 years old.

Is there any available English word to describe his sudden death?

Comment: I don't think we need the salacious details of this tragedy. That it was "sudden" is good enough.

Comment: I edited out the exact details of his passing. It is a sad event, but we don't need to talk about it publicly.

Comment: This case in either Vietnamese or Chinese actually has a special word describing it. Hope that in English there is one as well to distinguish from other sudden death.

Comment: But you didn't, unless someone edited it back in.

Comment: @Al -- There was even more detail that someone put in, including how he looked. You can check the edit history.

Comment: Are you asking for a word that simply describes "sudden death", or one that describes "sudden death during sexual intercourse"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the facts of your case, I would say, another expression would be:

> unexpected death.

As in:

> I was shocked by my neighbor's unexpected death.

---

Your new question:

> Can I use the word "breakstroke" for this case ?

The normal term is just "stroke," the result of a rupture of a blood vessel.

Comment: _Unexpected_ doesn't say anything about the manner or even speed of death which is the focus of this event. His death might have been unexpected if he was in generally good health, but the phrase doesn't carry the implications the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps someone else has heard of one, but I think that the shortest phrase you can get to describe a sudden death is, in fact, *sudden death*.

Comment: +1 Ha ha - your answer reminds me of mine [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33159/what-is-the-opposite-of-abstain/33161#33161).

Answer (score 0):

A relative of my friend's died suddenly after one night; he was badly drunk that night. I don't know why he died, I guess it was related to the malfunctions of blood circulation and brain's activities. Sadly, it was an **unexpected sudden death**.